# Realtime team sync for Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm starting a project with my team and we thought about using git to cooperate, anyway we're looking in a more automatic solution (eg. I may mention "Saros" for Eclipse) that automatic sync our project on Android Studio
How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about source control, but you could have a dropbox file hooked up the the project file in C:/users/androidstudioprojects/projectname. And then you could push from dropbox to the online jenkins code compiler to make sure it's error free. It's still hands on, other than the dropbox portion, but it helps keep version control of your apps and make sure they are error free.
I hope some of this info helps.

Comment: This can be done by a Git repository, we're searching a realtime sync, without needs to reload the file.

Comment: @HAlexTM I don't know of many ways to do this through windows. But if you are using linux you could setup a script that runs git.push and then specify the branch. But unless android has built in source control there is no way you are going to be able to get an auto updating file with no reloads.